# Second JOptionPane.showInputDialog not opening

Tags: java, swing

package minFinder;
/*
 * Takes two values from the User and and finds the smaller value 
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class minFinder {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double num1, num2;

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the first number");
    num1 = keyboard.nextDouble();

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the second number");
    num2 = keyboard.nextDouble();

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Math.min(num1, num2));
}
```

}

Here is the code that is troubling me, for whatever reason, the second and third  dialog boxes will not open, can I get some help with this? I feel like the solution is probably obvious.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using an `inputDialog` AND asking the user to enter a value via the command line?  It doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for whatever reason, the second and third dialog boxes will not open,

The Scanner is waiting for you to enter data from the keyboard.

Get rid of the Scanner class. If you are going to use a GUI then you don't need input from the keyboard.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Getting Input From the User](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input) for examples of using a `JOptionPane`.

Comment: I assume you will update to show "how" the OP should be using a `inputDialog`, so I'll just +1 now

Answer (score 1):

The Scanner only takes input from the console. Input dialogs already have a GUI that takes input, so you can get rid of the scanner.

The reason the second and third dialogs aren't being shown is because the first scanner is still waiting for an input, even if some text has been entered into the input dialog. The first one is working because the Scanner isn't waiting for any input.

Here's the correct code:

```
package minFinder; /* * Takes two values from the User and and finds the smaller value */

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class minFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double num1, num2;

        num1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the first number"));
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the first number"));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Math.min(num1, num2)); //Note how I changed it to a message dialog
    }
}
```

Some other things you should consider are that class names should start with capital letters, and package names should be completely lowercase.

The code above does not actually check that the entered string is a double, so if it's an invalid number, a NumberFormatException will be thrown. One way around this would be to do the following:

```
package minFinder; /* * Takes two values from the User and and finds the smaller value */

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class minFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;
        boolean invalidNumber;

        try {
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the first number"));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            invalidNumber = true;
            while(invalidNumber) {
                try {
                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid number. Please try again"));
                    invalidNumber = false;
                } catch(NumberFormatException e2) {}
            }
        }

        try {
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the second number"));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            invalidNumber = true;
            while(invalidNumber) {
                try {
                    num2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid number. Please try again"));
                    invalidNumber = false;
                } catch(NumberFormatException e2) {}
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Math.min(num1, num2));
    }
}
```

Here's some more information about dialogs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html